# RsJX 'Map' operator is not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, rxjs6

I'm trying to use `map` operator from RxJS but it throws an error saying

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Here is the code

```js
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { Http } from "@angular/http";
    import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
    @Injectable()

    export class DataService {
     constructor(public http: Http) {}

     getData() {
       return this.http
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .map(res => res.json());
      }
    }
```

Comment: which angular version do you use?

Comment: @ninjadev1030 Angular 6.0.9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For first `Http` is deprecated in higher versions than ***Angular 4***. Instead of it you need to use `HttpClient` with `HttpClientModule` from `"@angular/common/http"`. And using `HttpClient` you will get the *JSON* parsed result, so you don't need `res.json()` longer.

For second `map` in new verions of *RxJS* is being used another way. It is now pipeable, you need to use it combined with `pipe`.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()    
export class DataService {
  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getData() {
    return this.httpClient
               .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
  }
}
```

Using `map` operator

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

someFunction() {
   this.httpClient.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
                  .pipe(map(res) => something with res);
}

...
```

Comment: Thank you. Plus i had to import 'HttpClientModule' instead of only 'HttpModule' in "app.module.ts". And now its working good :)

Comment: @Rocktim Thanks. About HttpClientModule I have mentioned it above )

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was importing map operator like import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; this. instead of import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

Answer (score 5):

in RXJS 6 `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
getData() {
   return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
   .pipe(
        map(res => res.json())
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable()

export class DataService {
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 getData() {
   return this.http
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: This still won't work if using newer versions of RXJS, and also if using `HttpClient` then there is no need for `res.json()` anyway